# Failure to connect QGIS to FIRMS WMS - Failed to download capabilities

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server, connection

I'm following [this tutorial](https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/tutorials/qgis/) from (NASA) FIRMS that shows how to ingest FIRMS fire data into QGIS.

I've followed the first steps but I get the following error:

```
Failed to download capabilities
server replied: Not Found
```

[image: QGIS Error Message]

I've tried the URLs `https://localhost.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms/key/YOUR_MAP_KEY/` (as shown in the tutorial's text) and `https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms/key/YOUR_MAP_KEY/` (as shown in the tutorial's image, makes more sense but I'm no programmer).

I did replace "YOUR_MAP_KEY" with my actual key. A free MAP_KEY can be obtained [here](https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/mapserver/wms-info/#firms-mapkey).

I've also tried to check the URL in a browser but I get a "Unexpected request" error.

I'm using QGIS 3.22.1 on Windows.

*PS: I feel like this is a simple error but I didn't find other people with the same issue, and I'm not used to connecting to outside servers. I've searched for a while but I'm stuck with this.*

Comment: try the newer links 'https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/mapserver/wms/fires/YourMapKey' source https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/mapserver/wms-info/#firms-wms

Comment: @Mapperz that worked, thanks! :)